# Read config(Having nested configuration)file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, config

I have a `.config` file, which has data like:

```
category1 {

  Key1="value1"

  Key2="value2"

}

category2 {

  Key1="value1"

  Key2="value2"

}
```

How do I read these values in bash?

I want to access these values in my bash script.
Is there any way, to get it like `$category1.key1`

Comment: I don't know of any tool that can read it natively, so it's important to know which patterns you can have in the file: **1)** Nested "categories"? **2)** Multiple "categories" or "keys" in a single line? **3)** Spaces or escaped characters in the double-quotes? => Edit your question and make your sample example illustrate the possible border cases that you can find in the file

Comment: Not easily. What defined this configuration format, and what (else) expects to read from it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not json, so I am guessing you want to export environment variables to current shell. Then, assuming your file is 'some-config.conf' AND it is not nested crazy or anything:

```
shopt -s extglob
while read -r; do 
    #$REPLY is the default variable, assign it as you wish
    if [[ "${REPLY}" =~ [{}] ]]
    then
        #ignore or use '!' within if test
        :
    else 
        #process the line but remove leading spaces first
        declare -x "${REPLY##+([ ])}"
    fi
    #While reading line by line, ignore empty lines by 'grep -v'
done < <(cat some-config.conf | grep -Ev "^\s*$" )

#at this point you can do `echo ${Key1}`
```

if you want to export them to current shell, save it as 'parse.sh' and call:

```bash
. parse.sh
```